# Git Team Portal

Tags: git, collaboration

Is there a tool/system or module that I can use for team collaboration that interacts with Git?  I'm looking for something I can track tickets, maybe a wiki, and most importantly a git repository browser.  Ideally I could plug these pieces in to an existing site, but either would work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It interacts with Git and many other versioning systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) with GitPlugin. It also has plugins for mercurial, bazaar and many others.

Answer (score 0):

git repo browser, wiki and ticket system ... github has a comercial product that is very good at all of these...

Also you can look at the Atlassian suite of products... fish eye, confluence... etc.